# UIDocumentPickerViewController Limitations, Multiple Files selection at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickervc

In order to be able to access iCloud Drive from the application,
I think that we want to use UIDocumentPickerViewController from the application.
but i found following problems when i use UIDocumentPickerViewController.

1. Cannot upload multiple files at once.
2. Cannot Download multiple files at once.
3. When pushViewController from navigationController then display
   become strange.

I want to avoid above problems, **So is there any another way to get files information from iCloudDrive without using UIDocumentPickerViewController?
like Send some request or query.**

I have searched lot and didn't find any query or request to get Files ,Upload files and download files from iCloudDrive.

if you have any idea about this please tell me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any straightforward alternative, but you could think of...

- ...using iCloud directly (not iCloud *Drive*), but then users will only have access to their files from your application
- ...using Google Drive's sharing extension which supports uploading multiple files at once (the Dropbox SDK probably supports that, too, but their sharing extension doesn't)
- ...zipping all files before uploading them
- ...changing the file format so that it's a bundle of multiple files, if you are in control of the file format
- ...file a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/)/feature request, and possibly wait forever ;)

Not sure if that helps, but I don't think you have much of a choice here.